# Office JS Dialog - How to get back/keep context with Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I'm messing around w/ Office Dialog for Add-Ins in JS. I've got it so far where I can open a dialog, capture input to console, run a function from a button and close the dialog box, but I can't seem to get my function to interact with Excel. It's lost `context` I beleive, I tried using this and I get no errors, but it doesn't work --> `var context = new Excel.RequestContext()`.

Here is my open function and my main function and the end function.

main.js

```
export async function helloworld(event) {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            //Start Func
            console.log("BEFORE OPEN UI");
            openDialog("/yo/dist/dialog.html", 30, 20);
            console.log("AFTER OPEN UI");
            await context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("AFTER SYNC UI");
                    var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
                    var range = ws.getRange("A1:D5");
                    range.select();
                })
            //End Func
            await context.sync();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    console.log("EVENT COMPLETEED HELLOW");
    //event.completed();
}
```

open.js

```
function openDialog(RelURLStr, H, W) {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + RelURLStr,
        { height: H, width: W }, dialogCallback);
}
```

run func //this gets ran, but nothing output to worksheet and no errors.

```
function dobuttonrun(event) {
    console.log("ENDING");
    var context = new Excel.RequestContext()
    var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var fakedatarng = ws.getRange("A1");
    fakedatarng.values = "TEST";
    return context.sync();
    event.completed();
}

function getGlobal() {
    return typeof self !== "undefined"
        ? self
        : typeof window !== "undefined"
            ? window
            : typeof global !== "undefined"
                ? global
                : undefined;
}

const g = getGlobal();

// The add-in command functions need to be available in global scope
g.dobuttonrun = dobuttonrun;
```

Answer (score 1):

Opening a popup has UX issues on web clients. If you need to support excel web, it will ask the user a confirmation for the dialog each time and cannot by bypassed; Excel is asking not the browser!

I strongly suggest you, to use a Popup from your UX framework. If you are using Fluent UI, the microsoft suggested framework that keeps look and feel of office please refer to [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/dialog).

---

In case that you need a dialog solution, keep in mind that you are running a new page `/yo/dist/dialog.html` you'll loose all the variables and context from your parent webpage:

If you are using any SPA javascript framework like react.js or VUE.js, another clean app will be rendered.

BTW You can achieve your need implementing a simple communication as follows:

```js
// Office.Dialog type
let dialog;

export async function helloworld(event) {
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
    '/yo/dist/dialog', 
    { promptBeforeOpen: true, height: 70, width: 50, displayInIframe: false },
    (result) => {

      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        // unable to manage status
        throw new Error(result.error.message)
      }
      else {
        dialog = result.value;
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, messageHandler);
      }
    }
  )
}

/**
 * Assign the project to an employee.
 * @param {Object} arg - Event handler args
 * @param {string} arg.message - Message as string (NOT js OBJECT)
 * @param {string} arg.origin - Message Origin
 */
const messageHandler = (arg) => {
  // messaging can send only strings.
  // If you need to pass complex JSON you need to stringify and parse objects
  const message = JSON.parse(arg.message)

  if (message.type === "execution-canceled") {
    // you have all props of message like message.reason
    dialog.close();
    return
  }

  if (message.type === "execution-confirmed") {
    // execute than close popup
    // if you need to close popup than execute, just run dialog.close()
    // before doStuff() and remove finally method call
    doStuff()
      .then(() => console.log("EVENT COMPLETEED HELLOW"))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => dialog.close())
  }
}

const doStuff = async () => Excel.run(async (context) => {
  // you don't need context.sync() before interacting excel
  var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
  var range = ws.getRange("A1:D5");
  range.select();
  await context.sync();
})
```

On your dialog page you need to wait for `Office.initialize` in order to use `Office.context.ui.messaging apis`, than you can simply send your object.

```js
const send = (message) => {
  Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify(message));
}

Office.initialize = () => {
  // render page or activate button
}

const onExecutionConfirmed = () => send({ type: 'execution-confirmed' })

const onExcecutionCanceled = () => send({ 
  type: 'execution-canceled', 
  reason: "additional infos can be placed in any props of this serialized JSON object" 
})
```

Comment: I'm unsure why you removed my edit for `event.completed();` but it will cause Add-In to hang/fail without it. Additionally, you should provide a full URL or use `window.location.origin + /file.html`

Comment: Regardless, this code got me 100% where I wanted!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finished with after [@CLAudio detailed answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70839142/5079799)

**commands.js**

```
Office.onReady(() => {
    // If needed, Office.js is ready to be called
});

export async function helloworld(event) {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            //Start Func
            openDialog("/yo/dist/dialog.html", 30, 20);
            //End Func
            await context.sync();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    event.completed();
}

const doStuff = async () => Excel.run(async (context) => {
    // you don't need context.sync() before interacting excel
    var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var range = ws.getRange("A1:D5");
    range.select();
    await context.sync();
})

//////////////////////////////////////////
let dialog;

function openDialog(HTMLUrl, H, W) {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + HTMLUrl, { promptBeforeOpen: true, height: H, width: W, displayInIframe: false },
        (asyncResult) => {

            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                // In addition to general system errors, there are 3 specific errors for 
                // displayDialogAsync that you can handle individually.
                switch (asyncResult.error.code) {
                    case 12004:
                        console.log("Domain is not trusted");
                        break;
                    case 12005:
                        console.log("HTTPS is required");
                        break;
                    case 12007:
                        console.log("A dialog is already opened.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                dialog = asyncResult.value;
                /*Messages are sent by developers programatically from the dialog using office.context.ui.messageParent(...)*/
                dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, messageHandler);

                /*Events are sent by the platform in response to user actions or errors. For example, the dialog is closed via the 'x' button*/
                dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, eventHandler);
            }
        }
    )
}

function eventHandler(arg) {

    // In addition to general system errors, there are 2 specific errors 
    // and one event that you can handle individually.
    switch (arg.error) {
        case 12002:
            console.log("Cannot load URL, no such page or bad URL syntax.");
            break;
        case 12003:
            console.log("HTTPS is required.");
            break;
        case 12006:
            // The dialog was closed, typically because the user the pressed X button.
            console.log("Dialog closed by user");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Undefined error in dialog window");
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Assign the project to an employee.
 * @param {Object} arg - Event handler args
 * @param {string} arg.message - Message as string (NOT js OBJECT)
 * @param {string} arg.origin - Message Origin
 */
const messageHandler = (arg) => {
    // messaging can send only strings.
    // If you need to pass complex JSON you need to stringify and parse objects
    const message = JSON.parse(arg.message)
    console.log("message:")
    console.log(message)
    if (message.type === "execution-canceled") {
        // you have all props of message like message.reason
        dialog.close();
        return
    }

    if (message.type === "execution-confirmed") {
        // execute than close popup
        // if you need to close popup than execute, just run dialog.close()
        // before doStuff() and remove finally method call
        doStuff()
            .then(() => console.log("doStuff .then"))
            .catch(error => console.error(error))
            .finally(() => dialog.close())
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////
```

**dialog.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Contoso Task Pane Add-in</title>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
    <!-- For the Office UI Fabric, go to http://aka.ms/office-ui-fabric to learn more. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer" src="dialog.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <p class="ms-font-xxl ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semilight">Pick a number</p>
    <button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" id="run">
        <span class="ms-Button-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--plus"></i></span>
        <span class="ms-Button-label" id="runbutton-text">RUN</span>
        <span class="ms-Button-description" id="runbutton-desc">Run Func</span>
    </button>
    <button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" id="close">
        <span class="ms-Button-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--plus"></i></span>
        <span class="ms-Button-label" id="closebutton-text">EXIT</span>
        <span class="ms-Button-description" id="closebutton-desc">Exit Func</span>
    </button>
    <form>
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**dialog.js**

```
Office.initialize = () => {
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = onExecutionConfirmed;
    document.getElementById("close").onclick = onExcecutionCanceled;
}

const send = (message) => {
    Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify(message));
}

const onExecutionConfirmed = () => send({ type: 'execution-confirmed' })


const onExcecutionCanceled = () => send({
    type: 'execution-canceled',
    reason: "additional infos can be placed in any props of this serialized JSON object"
})
```